# Rails 4: How to display file_field and error_messages when no image selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

`<%= p.file_field :image %>` and an error message aren't appeared when I click the submit  button in `_article_form.html.erb` with entering nothing.

`<%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "enter..." %>` and the error message for this text_area are displayed.

How can I display `<%= p.file_field :image %>` and error messages?

views\articles\new.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span8">
    <%= render 'shared/article_form' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

views\shared_article_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p| %>
      <% if p.object.image and p.object.image.file %>
        <%= image_tag p.object.image.thumb.url %>
        <p><%= p.object.image.file.filename %></p>
      <% end %>
      <%= p.file_field :image %>
      <br>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "enter..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

\controllers\articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @article = Article.new
    .
    .
    .
    3.times { @article.photos.build }
  end

  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:success] = "article created!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
       render 'new'
    end
  end
    .
    .
    .
  private

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:content, :stock_id, photos_attributes: [:id, :article_id, :image])
    end

end
```

\models\article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    .
    .
    .
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:image].blank? }
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
    .
    .
    .
end
```

\models\photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
    validates :image, presence: true
end
```

**Update**

I edited the code and the current situation is as below.

When I click the submit button with no content and no image, error messages and `f.text_area :content` are displayed. `p.file_field :image` isn't displayed.

When I click the submit button with content and no image, error message and `f.text_area :content` are displayed. `p.file_field :image` isn't displayed.

When I click the submit button with no content and more than one image, error message and `f.text_area :content` are displayed. `p.file_field :image` is also displayed depending on the number of images. I expect 3 `p.file_field :image` are always displayed despite the number of images I select.

When I click the submit button with content and more than one image, it works.

\models\article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
.
.
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes[:image].blank? }
    validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
.
.
    validate :check_for_at_least_image

    def check_for_at_least_image
      errors.add(:image, " select at least one") if self.photos.size <= 0
    end
```

end

\models\photo.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
#   validates :image, presence: true    #comment out this line
end
```

Comment: do you want an error message to appear if there is no image uploaded? Not quite getting it...

Comment: Sorry didn't realise that. Not sure as I haven't tried it but I think since you want to validate it you'll have to remove reject if proc as it'll simply reject if your image is blank. You can also make a custom validation where you could reject blank values and validate at least one image but not sure. Will get back to it after I have some code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using accept nested attributes so you *just need to add a **validation on your image field in photo.rb** and if a user doesn't input image in form then it'll show you error, so your photos.rb will look like this:*

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  validates :image, presence: true
end
```

**Update:**

Your custom validation would be something like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  .
  validate :check_for_at_least_image

  def check_for_at_least_image
      errors.add(:image, "select at least one") if self.photos.size <= 0
  end
end
```

**Update**

For some reason article doesn't build your nested attribute after validation error so in your create action you can do like this:

```
def create
  @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)
  if @article.save
    flash[:success] = "article created!"
    redirect_to current_user
  else
     3.times { @article.photos.build } if @article.photos.blank? #this will build your images if it's empty and if it isn't then it'll simply render your file_fields
     render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mandeep. I have already added the validation you advised in photo.rb. So I updated the code which I use. I would appreciate if you could advise.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue it didn't work for you? I think a problem could be that you are using both reject_if proc on image and then validating it too

Comment: thank you for your comment. I'd like to check one file is mandatory. As you provided the answer to [my another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225939/rails-4-how-to-upload-multiple-images-using-carrierwave), I can check if there's at least one image present. It would be appreciated if you could be a little more specific about checking no image is selected.

Comment: Thank you very much for always answering.

I tried your custom validation, but it doesn't work what I expect.

I commented out `reject_if: proc` and added `check_for_at_least_image` you advised.

When I click the submit button after selecting one image and inputting `f.text_area`, the error message is displayed to select another two images.

It would be appreciated if you could provide an alternate way.
What I want to do is for users to select at least one image (up to 3 images) and to enter f.text_area.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue can you edit your question and post your model codes because i have tested it in a demo app and it seems to work for me

Comment: I update the current situation. If you need more information, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue you need to update your question not my answer :)

Comment: I update my question... I'm still trying to get used to stackoverflow.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue ok just tested and i can reproduce it. Don't know why it's happening. Updated my anwer, it seems like a bug though check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611543/rails-fields-for-does-not-render-after-validation-error-on-nested-form.

Comment: I always appreciate your help.  I edited articles_controller.rb, but the error messages `NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create` `undefined method 'images' for #<Article:0x6735960>` are displayed. I have used a strong parameter `article_params` in articles_controller.rb as you may know, so I updated the code in the original question. I tried some of the codes like `if @article.photos.images.blank?` or `if @article.photos.image.blank?` in articles_controller.rb , but they didn't turn out right.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue @article.photos.image.blank? should work for you

Comment: I also thoguht it would work, but it didn't work as I commented. When I try `@article.photos.image.blank?`, the following error is displayed. `NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create` and `undefined method 'image' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

Comment: @SamuraiBlue ahh okay i think i know whats causing this. Try @article.photos.blank?

Comment: thank you for your advise. There is no error message when I use `@article.photos.blank?`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `reject_if` option for `accept_nested_attributes_for`.
You're rejecting photos from being built without an image present. So, thus photos are never built, there is nothing to validate and nowhere errors to come from.